# How do I impose a slot limit for sge on my user without manager rights?

Tags: gridengine

On our cluster I could use up all the slots with the current configuration of sge. I don't want to overuse my privileges by accident / check at every submit.

Is there a way to impose a hard limit on the number of slots my jobs can use?

I don't have manager rights, so I can't do as in the question "[How can I set the maximum number of running jobs per user on SGE?](https://serverfault.com/q/184165/153155)" Although that would be exactly what I am after.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a recent grid engine and you are submitting a bunch of jobs with identical resource requirements you could try submitting as a single array job limited by the `-tc` switch.  The following command would
submit a job of 100000 tasks but only run 100 at a time:

```
qsub -t 1-100000 -tc 100 script.sh
```